# Dissociative Identity Disorder or Schizophrenia?

Tags: characters, child-characters

I have a ten-year-old character, called Theodore, who suffers from mental disorders. He one night unconsciously kills his twin brother, Matthews, by smothering him with a pillow. Unaware of his deeds, he comes back to his bed and continues sleeping as if nothing happened, to wake up in the morning shocked by the death of his brother.
This incident was the reason for him to adopt Matthews' personality, in other words, he starts to live with two personalities, his, and his brother's, which I'm not sure to call it [**Dissociative Identity Disorder**](https://www.webmd.com/mental-health/dissociative-identity-disorder-multiple-personality-disorder) or [**Schizophrenia**](https://www.webmd.com/schizophrenia/default.htm).

Also, I would like to see your views on the idea, is it logical, worth giving it a try?

Comment: I don't think your main question is on-topic, but to throw you a bone, what you describe would be dissociative identity disorder. Schizophrenia is a completely different mental disorder. Whether your planned portrayal of someone with DID is a good idea, however, would be a perfectly acceptable question.

Comment: "Strangle" would normally be used if your character squeezed the throat.  With a pillow, you'd usually call it "smothering."

Comment: @JRE suffocate might also work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Be very careful and sensitive when writing a character with a real-world major personality disorder. *Especially* a villain.

If you're going to portray an *explicitly* and medically diagnosed [schizophrenic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/schizophrenia/symptoms-causes/syc-20354443#:%7E:text=Schizophrenia%20is%20a%20serious%20mental,with%20schizophrenia%20require%20lifelong%20treatment.) or [Dissociative Identity Disorder (DID)](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/9792-dissociative-identity-disorder-multiple-personality-disorder#:%7E:text=from%20Cleveland%20Clinic-,Dissociative%20identity%20disorder%20(DID)%20is%20a%20mental%20health%20condition.,memory%20loss%2C%20delusions%20or%20depression.) character, and you make that diagnosis clear in your story, **I would strongly advise you to consult a sensitivity reader, doctor, or qualified psychiatrist, or do a lot of research on those disorders before going forward.** There is a lot of care and caution that goes into portraying a character (*especially* a villain) with any kind of real-world major personality disorder, without falling into reductive stereotypes or not fully capturing what it means and how it feels to have that kind of debilitating mental illness, and to fall into the common traps is to contribute to the greater misrepresentation problem that plagues writing of this kind. Understand that your villain is not going to be murderous purely *because* of their personality disorder, and make that crystal-clear in your writing. Far too many authors, both old and new, write schizophrenic or dissociative characters as one-dimensional villains who are murderous, "crazy" and "psychotic," mimicking the ["Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde" good personality vs. evil personality stereotype](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/JekyllAndHyde), which has greatly contributed to the negative popular perception, misunderstandings, and even outright *fear* of real-life people who suffer from personality disorders. The majority of schizophrenic people in the real world suffer greatly from both their positive and negative symptoms, face misunderstandings and inconsistent treatment from the medical community, struggle to be gainfully employed, and are more likely to be the *victims* of crimes than the actual perpetrators, and portraying a schizophrenic or dissociative person as starkly "evil" and a psychotic murderer because of their disorder can be insensitive at best and downright irresponsible at worst.

This doesn't mean you *can't* have a villain like this, and I'm not saying to avoid it. But **since your question is *specifically referencing the medical diagnosis you are giving this character in-universe,* you are implicitly saying that this character should generally be accurate to real-world people with those disorders**, hence why I'm writing this kind of answer. With DID you should practice special caution, as the disorder is highly contested and controversial in the medical community, and greatly misunderstood by pop culture and society as a whole - many people do not fully believe it is a real category of disorder, while others believe people with DID are feigning the disorder for attention. The research is hard to collate on the topic and there is much nuance to consider, so just be aware that the minefield exists and you should be cautious when navigating it to write a character with the disorder as sensitively as possible.

### What is there to consider when writing a schizophrenic or dissociative character?

Consider each of the following pieces of information to guide you in writing a character like this.

**For a schizophrenic character...**

- **Research positive and negative symptoms.** Understand the ways in which schizophrenia would typically manifest - *especially* in a young child, which is not a very common or well-understood age group for this type of disorder. While schizophrenia can manifest at any age, [the average age of onset is the early or late 20s,](https://www.nami.org/About-Mental-Illness/Mental-Health-Conditions/Schizophrenia#:%7E:text=Although%20schizophrenia%20can%20occur%20at,to%20live%20well%20with%20schizophrenia.) so a childhood presentation as young as this will be very unusual.

  - Common schizophrenia symptoms include disorganized speech or behavior, difficulty concentrating, memory problems, social isolation, compulsive behavior, incoherency and delusions, and many more. Decide how your character fits into this typical medical profile.
- **Understand and research delusions and psychosis, which typically occur in three stages for schizophrenic people.** Psychotic episodes are not simply "killing sprees" or "murderous rampages" where a character loses touch with reality. While being out of touch with real life is a common part of a psychotic break, the most common manifestations of psychosis will be visual and auditory hallucinations, agitation, confusion, loss of motivation, and disturbed thinking or memories; it is *extremely rare* for a delusional episode to result in homicidal mania or murder, unlike what movies and television would lead us to believe. [Typical schizophrenic psychotic episodes have three phases: prodrome, acute, and recovery,](https://medicine.yale.edu/psychiatry/step/psychosis/phasis/) each of which have different symptoms and manifestations. Your character's psychotic episodes will generally follow this pattern, so research each stage and make sure you understand how to write each step of the progression.
- **Remember that not every schizophrenic person has multiple personalities.** Mixing up DID and schizophrenia is a common trap to fall into, and while the disorders can be comorbid and there are schizophrenic people who have multiple "identities" in a DID-like sense, not all of them have that specific profile.

**For a Dissociative Identity Disorder (DID) character...**

- **Understand what causes it.** [As many as 90% of patients with DID developed the disorder after severe child abuse, post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD), or other trauma.](https://archive.org/details/diagnosticstatis0005unse/page/291) It has also been linked to substance abuse and is comorbid with other disorders. For a young child to develop DID, they will almost certainly have suffered a major trauma in their life, as it rarely develops in young children without a large instigating event. The disorder is *vanishingly rare* in children, which is part of the why the disorder is so controversial and contested in the medical community, so you'd need to have a very strong reason to present a child character with DID.
- **Research its symptoms and effects.** DID does not ever happen in a vacuum, and it is not just having more than one personality - it is strongly linked to obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD), sleep disorders, self-harm, non-epileptic seizures, and suicidal ideations. A person with DID likely has a large psychiatric profile, and will have a variety of other symptoms and comorbid illnesses and a varying medical presentation; according to some sources, people with DID can have as many as five to seven comorbid illnesses and disorders.
- **Understand the types of personalities that tend to manifest.** As stated before, it won't be as simple as them having "good" and "evil" people living in their head. According to real people with DID, these personalities are known as **"alters."** Some common types of alters that manifest include "protection" alters, "animal" alters, "fictive" alters and many more. Research these "alters" and decide how many and which types your character will have, and why they might have each one.
- **Be careful of stereotypes.** Writing a character with multiple "good" and "evil" personalities a la [Split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(2016_American_film)), slapping a DID diagnosis on them and calling it a day might be sufficient for your story, but you might be contributing to the popular misunderstanding of the illness and will *absolutely* be walking into a minefield when your story gets in the hands of mental health advocates. The symptoms and medical presentation of DID is highly contested in the medical and psychiatric community, and the disorder has been greatly dramatized and exaggerated by popular culture to the point where most people understand it as merely "having multiple personalities" and "not remembering what each personality does," without any additional nuance or understanding of the clinical presentation of the disorder. Do not allow yourself to fall into that trap too, even if it's just for an innocent one-time portrayal.

### In short... (tl:dr;)

**Please, please do your research** before you write this character. It's the best and most respectful step you can take when writing any kind of character with a mental illness you do not personally have, and it is better to spend a few hours understanding something better than to spend months (maybe even *years*) fighting off criticism of your story after publication. I hope that this answer, however long-winded, will be helpful to your research going forward.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! It really is helpful and it alerted me :) Though, I guess writing this type of character is really hard that I think I need to more improve my knowledge and writing skills first.